# Routing in MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, pgrouting

```
CREATE INDEX source_idx ON road_network("source");

CREATE INDEX target_idx ON road_network("target");

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN length double precision;

UPDATE road_network  SET length = length(the_geom);

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN reverse_cost double precision;

UPDATE road_network  SET reverse_cost = length;

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN x1 double precision;

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN y1 double precision;

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN x2 double precision;

ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN y2 double precision;

UPDATE road_network  SET x1 = x(ST_PointN(the_geom, 1));

UPDATE road_network  SET y1 = y(ST_PointN(the_geom, 1));

UPDATE road_network  SET x2 = x(ST_PointN(the_geom, ST_NumPoints(the_geom)));

UPDATE road_network  SET y2 = y(ST_PointN(the_geom, ST_NumPoints(the_geom)));

alter table road_network add column cost double precision default 0;

update road_network set cost=0.1 where type='NH';

update road_network set cost=0.2 where type='SH';

update road_network set cost=0.3 where type='major';

update road_network set cost=0.4 where type='minor';

update road_network set cost=1.2 where type='colony';
```

This is the query I am using for routing in pgrouting ?

**My Query**
Is it possible to create routing in MSSQL?

If so what are all the functions available in SQL Spatial?

Comment: question makes no sense.

Comment: Is it possible to do routing in MSSQL ?

Comment: Comment still makes no sense.. :S

Comment: do u know routing in postgresSQL or not ?

Answer (score 0):

In general all the PostGIS methods that implements the **SQL-MM** specification (you can see them for examle [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ch08.html) - they have the appropriate comment) have their analogs in SQL Server because geometry data type [compliant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) with **SQL-MM** (ISO standard)

All routing/spatial funcions from your code exist in SQL Server.